# Is it correct to say "I have not done enough to say no"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence

I am an international student and writing my Statement of Purpose.

To give you some context, my client asked me a question that I didn't know the answers, but at the same time I felt like I did not try hard enough to figure out the answers, can I say in my SOP that "[...] I have not done enough to say no"? Does this sentence make sense and deliver what I was trying to say?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the right way to answer would be "I don't know enough to answer yet."